# Checkbox selection functionality not working as expected in tree view

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am working on angular material tree table where I need to add manually checkbox functionality for my tree table.
When all child nodes are selected parent node must get selected and  when unselected parent also should be unselected. At this point i am facing issues which is not working and partial selection woks as expected. I am using one mat checkbox for this use case .

[stackblitz code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-tree-example-7nffyw?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

Comment: I couldn't understand your issue. I tried the 'Fruit' and it seems to work as expected - parent gets checked only when all children are checked and gets unchecked when all children are unchecked.

Comment: please check once 'vegetable' node there you can find issue.
you can check here the second level object how t works same i need for my tree table.
https://stackblitz.com/angular/nkmjydodvnp?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts.

Comment: Issue here is I need to send parent node and children node separately to mat checkbox but how to get parent and children is not getting.

Answer (score 0):

It is working. I am sharing link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-tree-example-caddt5?file=app/table-basic-example.ts

Comment: just tree level functionality i need. un select of all leaf should unselect its parent also i think that is not working in link which you shared.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-tree-example-yuqmbg?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html. 
edited now .
issue seems to be there still. when we uncheck allleaf nodes its parent must be unchecked and select all functionality not required in header

Comment: anyone please help me out to identify what's missing in code.